# Not a java source folder error while creating a servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am working on a dynamic web project and when I try to create a servlet inside the src directory (or even after creating a package inside src directory) eclipse says not a java source folder and doesnt let me create this servlet. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the folder in **Project Explorer**, select **Build path** > **Use as source folder**.

Comment: I am able to create the servlet now, thanks, but the automatically generated syntax are asking me to create an HttpServlet class and not finding it automatically from the superclass. I have specified javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet in superclass while creating the servlet.

Comment: The required libraries are not on your build path.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is having the same issue, try this.
Go to properties of the project -> Project facets, then check whether dynamic web module is selected or not, If not select it. If it is selected deselect it and apply. Then go back and select it back and apply.